# Adding a flash video to webpage

Tags: javascript, html, flash, flv

**Code**

```
<head>
    <meta name="description" content="Learning about flash" />
    <meta http-equiv="author" content="Abhi" />
    <title>Flash</title>

    <script type="text/javascript"
             src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js">         
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            var flashvars={};
            var params= {movie:"puppy.flv"};
            swfobject.embedSWF("C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe", "snow", "400", "320", "8.0.0", flashvars, params);
    </script>

</head>

<body>
        <div id="snow"><p> Alternative content: A video of puppy playing in the snow.</p></div>
</body>
```

**location of VLC:**  `C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe`

**location of .flv file:**  `F:\4. Codes\HTML\puppy.flv`

**location of  html file where I am writing code is:**  `F:\4. Codes\HTML\51_2.html`

But I am not able to see video on my html page rather I am seeing just alternative content. What's the problem ?

Comment: step 1. take a trip back in time, when flash was relevant :p

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to do something that makes no technical sense. You cannot allow a random local EXE program to run inside HTML page just because you want to.

Comment: PS: You can just use VLC itself to convert the FLV into MP4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash is not supported anymore in browsers so thats why it wont show: https://caniuse.com/?search=flash

Comment: is flash not supported for audio also ?

Comment: No whole flash is not supported anymore

Answer (score 1):

Flash is not supported now, you can read this https://www.adobe.com/sea/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html